# How to get back to the previous page while click on back button on browser using PHP and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

After redirecting to another page while user is trying to get back to the previous page is getting the below error message using PHP and MongoDB.

Error:

[image]

Here is my code:

search-result.php:

```
<h2 class="srhtmargin"><a href="companydetails.php?cid=<?php echo $vsrc['_id']; ?>" style="color: #2c3e50; float:left;"><img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $vsrc['image2']; ?>" alt="" border="0" /></a><a href="companydetails.php?cid=<?php echo $vsrc['_id']; ?>" style="color: #2c3e50"><?php echo $vsrc['cname']; ?></a></h2>
```

When user is clicking on the above link its redirecting to the `companydetails.php` page. Then when user is clicking on back button of browser on that (`i.e-companydetails.php`) page,the `search-result.php` url is coming  but its throwing the above message and while user is again reloading the page its coming.

about-us.php:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="headerform" role="search" name="search" action="search-result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control itextindent" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['qsearch']; ?>" placeholder="Review Title, Company Or Product Name" name="qsearch" id="qsearch" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

From the above page the user can get into the `search-result.php` page.

Here I need while user will click on back button it will return to the previous page(`search-result.php`) and the page will reload.

Comment: `mongodb` has no concern with redirecting.

Comment: I know that as i am using MongoDB thats why i attached there.

Comment: Confirm Form Re submission is not an error.

Comment: if you are using some kind of post request then that is the issue.

Comment: let me to add the post request to get into `search-result.php` page.

Comment: Please check my post again.